# Is it safe to say that same type of coffee used with an espresso machine is ideal for a moka pot?

Tags: espresso, moka, percolator

As far as the type of:

1. bean;
2. the better-suited roast;
3. proper grind-size goes;

...do you treat a moka pot's coffee (bean/roast/grind) the same way as a full espresso machine? I use a Bialetti Brikka - which makes a great shot, & even approximates a "crema" (though I know it isn't actually the same "crema" as with an espresso machine) and I always thought this moka pot is like having an espresso machine on your stovetop. So naturally, I would buy stronger Coffea Arabica varieties, roasted dark, but would only grind them to a medium/fine to suit the basket filter. But as far as bean & roast, I would match what most espresso machines use. Am I wrong to match this moka pot's bean preference to that of an espresso machine? Are they better utilized using completely different bean cocktails?

Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, let's clear the misconception. The posted photo in the question is a moka pot. This is a common misconception all around the globe and also discussed in [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) a few times. Please see the following post to clear this out:

- [Does a percolator make "better" coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/does-a-percolator-make-better-coffee)

A better answer, also including the differences in between an espresso and a moka (the cup made with a moka pot) is explained here:

- [What's the difference between a percolator and a moka pot?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/418/whats-the-difference-between-a-percolator-and-a-moka-pot)

Then, please check this answer regarding the crema and the pressure issues:

- [Generating crema with a moka pot?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/97/generating-crema-with-a-moka-pot/298#298)

---

**Enormous Editing** after farankoshan's change in the question is below.

If we decide to compare the moka pot (instead of a percolator) with espresso, then my answer is as follows. I keep the first version for history.

---

First, the grind size is very different. It is advised that ideal grind size for espresso is around **300 µ** where for a moka pot it is around **800 µ**.

It is also known that espresso brews are the most acidic cups and moka pots are produce generally bitter cups. A reference to espresso brews is below, unfortunately, this study does not include moka pots.

- [Could preparation method make coffee more acidic?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/349/could-preparation-method-make-coffee-more-acidic/)

According to this knowledge, you may decide your beans and roast as you please.

For the roast, it is known that acidity reduces when roast degree increases. That's why many espresso brews are prepared with darker roasts. You may search for your taste.

For the bean origin (or the blend) you may again search for the specific acidity and bitterness. JayCo's previous study below is a good starting point again.

- [What coffees are the least acidic?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/66/what-coffees-are-the-least-acidic/)

Comment: Noted all your comments, MT San. Thanks. Editing my question, and will wait for an answer.

Comment: @farankoshan, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think its wrong. Each method for coffee have speciality details. Absolutely grind size for espresso machine is different with mocha pot.

You can use the same grind size with different ratio. Ant this way make different body and different strength