# Brew a less acidic coffee

Tags: brewing-process, ground-coffee, acid

A recent visit to the dentist opened my eyes to a new aspect of tooth care I hadn't realized: apparently, the acidity of coffee can increase the growth of cavities if the teeth are not brushed directly after.  Unfortunately, brushing the teeth directly after my morning coffee isn't really an option.  Also, unequivocally, giving up my morning coffee isn't an option either.

That led me to wonder, is there any way of brewing a normal coffee in a way that would lead to a beverage with a higher pH, that still has the taste and caffeine of a normal coffee?

Comment: My guess would be that the best thing to do would be to drink water after drinking coffee. Swish the water around in your mouth if you're concerned. That will bring the acidity down to a point where it ought not affect your teeth. (I am not a dentist, a doctor, a nutritionist ....)

Comment: Yes, that's what the dentist suggested too, but I don't always have a water fountain close.

Comment: I'm not sure what he opened your eyes to, but before going out of your way doing weird things to your coffee you might consider dropping the occasional soft drink (also sugar free), sweets, beer, juice, tomatoes, lemon, pizza or anything else that contains sugar. There's even some evidence, that coffee prevents cavities as green tea most likely does:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2848806/

Comment: I would be interested in a study on this in general.  I would like to see someone with those pH strips for a pool or the soil meter for a garden and use them on different things for coffee to see in general.  I might have a new quirk and test to try (I do a French press and bring in a temperature gun to make sure my water is boiled just right and to test other coffees and waters that way...bought at Home Depot).  But overall, I would go with what avacado1 said.

Comment: Please see this relevant answer on brewing methods vs acidity as this may help you to choose an appropriate brewing method: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/349/could-preparation-method-make-coffee-more-acidic/

Comment: Keith the thing about acidity is also that most health benefits of coffee stem from these acids (like the chlorogenic acid which is one of the main constituents of coffee), which are strong antioxidants, preventing heart diseases, some forms of cancer etc. So there is some trade off involved and I think the benefits outweigh the disadvantages by far (and taste does as well in my opinion). Easier solution is to drink some water after your coffee, which you should do in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try switching to [cold brew coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_brew_coffee) which is reportedly [67% less acidic than regular brewed coffee](https://www.thedailybeast.com/coffees-dirty-little-secret).

Regarding the caffeine amount, Wikipedia notes:

> *Although less caffeine is extracted with the cold brew method, a higher coffee-to-water ratio is often used, between 2 and 2 1/2 times. This may compensate for this difference in solubility, resulting in a brew with equal, if not more, caffeine (although this is unlikely)*

Additionally, despite the name, *cold brew coffee can be enjoyed hot as well.* Cold brew is essentially a coffee concentrate if steeped long enough. You can cut your cold brew with boiling water and serve it hot ([Source](https://www.jamieoliver.com/news-and-features/features/how-to-make-cold-brew-coffee/)), so you don't need to necessarily change the way you enjoy your coffee (if you enjoy it hot).

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

An unsweetened cup of coffee is not the most harmful thing in the world. The sweeteners people often add is the culprit. [centraldental](https://www.centraldental.com/coffee-harm-teeth-much-think/)  Also use a balanced water.  Starting with a acidic pH water is not helpful.  There are numerous additives or waters available. I brush after consuming my coffees and do not drink same all day. IMHO to blame **just** coffee on cavities is wrong. The citation talks of some less acid coffee preps!

Comment: Careful when brushing immediately after acidic foods though, that [just encourages erosion](https://www.dentalhealth.org/diet-and-my-teeth). Better try chewing some [xylitol chewing gum after](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD010743.pub2/full).